# DB Design - participants in event

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following Problem and i dont know how to solve it properly yet.
In my MYSQL Database I have a table for events with a ID, name, etc. But also I want to store a list of participants. But the problem is that this list is of variable length. So what is the best way to store this list ? If you want you can compare this to Facebook Events where they have informations about the event itself and then tables for "going", "maybe", "no", "invited". How are those tables handled? Is there a specific table for each event? Because that would cause tons of tables or is there another trick?

I know this question should be a very simple one but I am kind of new to databases. 
Best Regards

Comment: Do you know what Primary and Foreign keys are and what they are for?  Have you heard of database normalization?

Comment: in the table participants, add a field to store the type( going, maybe, ...). it could be a foreign key of another table that stores these values and could have endless entries of course. Depending on your design, you may instead, add this new field to the events table

Comment: Yes i know what primary and foreign keys are what they are for. But one of the main questions is. Would i create a individual table with participants for each event or should it be one big participant table where I store the event number and the user id with status thus having 1 participant table for ALL events instead of having a single table for every single event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you may have 4 tables:

Events:(**EventID**,Name,.....)

Members:(**MemberID**,....)

Participations(**EventID**,**MemberID**,**ParticipationTypeID**)

ParticipationTypes(**ParticipationTypeID**,ParticipationTypeName)

the later table strore values such as "going",.."invited",...

field marked bold are primary keys

Comment: @user3340598 you're welcome, I'm glad that it was useful